# How to trigger a JavaFX event when all ListView CheckBoxes are checked?

Tags: java, listview, javafx, checkbox, jfoenix

How can i trigger an event when all JFXCheckBoxes inside the JFXListView are checked and when all unchecked ?

This is my code:

```
@FXML
private JFXListView li_se;

private void Services(ActionEvent e) {
        li_se.getItems().clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < R.OffrirService().size(); i++) {
            JFXCheckBox s = new JFXCheckBox(R.OffrirService().get(i));
            s.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasOn, isNowOn) -> {
                if (wasOn == false) {
                         //if checked do something                       
                } else {
                         //if unchecked do something
                }
                //System.out.println(s.getText() + " changed on state from " + wasOn + " to " + isNowOn);
            });
            li_se.getItems().add(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@FXML
private JFXListView li_se;

int d;

@FXML
private void Services(ActionEvent e) {
    try {
        li_se.getItems().clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < R.OffrirService().size(); i++) {
            JFXCheckBox s = new JFXCheckBox(R.OffrirService().get(i));
            s.selectedProperty().addListener((obs, wasOn, isNowOn) -> {
                if (wasOn == false) {
                    //if checked do something
                    d++;
                        if (d == R.OffrirService().size()) {
                            //if all checked do something
                        }
                } else {
                    //if unchecked do something
                    d--;
                        if (d == 0) {
                            //if all unchecked do something
                        }
                //System.out.println(s.getText() + " changed on state from " + wasOn + " to " + isNowOn);
            });
            li_se.getItems().add(s);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can explore Bindings.

There is example for 2 checkBox selected:

```
BooleanProperty bp = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);
CheckBox cb1 = new CheckBox();
CheckBox cb2 = new CheckBox();
bp.bind(Bindings.and(cb1.selectedProperty(), cb2.selectedProperty()));
bp.addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable, Boolean oldValue, Boolean newValue) {

    }
});
```

For multiple CheckBoxes some wierd idea arrived. I hope could explain it.
The main idea like unix chmod 000 - no access, 777 - all access.
For example you have five CBoxes. Let add some value to each.
CB1 value 1
CB2 value 2
CB3 value 3
CB4 value 4
CB5 value 5

And use someVariable to store total value of all selected CBoxes.
When none selected: someVariable == 0.
When all selected: someVariable == (1+2+3+4+5)

```
  IntegerProperty checkedNumbers = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
    checkedNumbers.addListener(new javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener<Number>() {
        @Override
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
            if (newValue == 0) {
                //doSomething
            } else if (newValue == (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5)) {
                //doSomethingElse
            }
        }
    });
    int cBoxNumbers = 5;

    //Implement same ChangeListener for every CBoxes based on different UserData.
    //When CB selected, add its value to checkedNumbers
    //When unselected - subtract
    ChangeListener changeListener;

    for (int i = 1; i <= cBoxNumbers; i++) {
        CheckBox cb1 = new CheckBox();
        cb1.setUserData(i);
        cb1.selectedProperty().addListener(changeListener);
    }
```

Comment: How can i bind a dynamic number of JFXCheckBoxes ?

Comment: Thank you that's the idea. i was able to do this like the answer below.